# Fragment disappears with ViewPager2 and FragmentStateAdapter

Tags: android, androidx, android-viewpager2

I'm building an app using `ViewPager2` that displays different fragments when swiped. My adapter extends `FragmentStateAdapter` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2).

When I put my app into the background and then resume again, the current fragment disappears. What do I need to do to make sure the current fragment is restored correctly?

(Note: I am asking about `FragmentStateAdapter`, not `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.)

**Update 1**:

My fragment class is as follows:

```
class PagerFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val layoutResId: Int = arguments!!.getInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID)
    return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false)
}

companion object {
    private const val ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID = "layoutResId"

    fun newInstance(layoutResId: Int): PagerFragment {
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putInt(ARG_LAYOUT_RES_ID, layoutResId)

        val fragment = PagerFragment()
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

}

I pass in the desired layout resource id for each fragment when it is created.

My view pager adapter class is as follows:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm) 
{
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return PagerFragment.newInstance(Helper.getLayoutResId(position))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Helper.getSize()
    }
}
```

Adding `retainInstance = true` does not resolve the problem.

**Update 2**:

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume()` in my main activity solves the problem for now, although it feels like a heavier hammer than should be necessary. (The original `ViewPager` + `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` does not require this type of call to reload fragments properly after bringing in the app from the background.)

**Update 3**:

Updating my dependency from `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha01` to the recently released `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha02` fixes the issue entirely :).

Comment: If you share your code it will be more clear. I think its involved with lifecycle of fragment and did you try to use setRetainInstance(true)?

Comment: See updated question :)

Comment: There isn't much detail here but one thing I can think of is that if you are dealing with nested Fragments you'd have to pass `childFragmentManager()` rather than `supportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @RodrigoQueiroz. I am not dealing with nested fragments, my `ViewPager2` is the root view of the main activity layout.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the inverse problem. The nested (child) fragment doesn't show first time, but does after bringing the App from the background.

Comment: Updating to a (now out-of-date) version of ViewPager resolved my issue. See Update 3 on my post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FragmentManager you need to pass your FragmentActivity or Fragment instance as FragmentStateAdapter constructor parameter.

```
private inner class ViewPagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {

     val fragments = arrayOf(
        MyFragment1(),
        MyFragment2()
    )

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragments.size
    }
}
```

Official Documentation: [Read Here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#adapter-constructors)